# Darkening an Item in recyclerView when clicked

Tags: android

I have a recyclerview and I was wondering how I would be able to darken the an item in the recycler view when it's clicked. It's basically like a grocery list but instead of having it strike through it darkens the area.

This is my ViewHolder

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    private TextView mTitle;

    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Row

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="90dp"
android:layout_height="90dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="15dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selector_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Color when the row is selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- Standard background color -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_selected="false" />
</selector>
```

`Adapter`

```
public class UpdateDataAdapter extends RecyclerView
        .Adapter<UpdateDataAdapter
        .DataObjectHolder> {

    private ArrayList<UpdateData> mDataset;
    private static Context mContext;
    private static int mPosition;
    private static SparseBooleanArray sSelectedItems;
    private static UpdateDataClickListener sClickListener;

    static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View
            .OnClickListener {
        TextView mLabel;
        TextView mDateTime;
        LinearLayout mBackground;


        DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vertical_list_item_title);
            mDateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vertical_list_item_subtitle);
            mBackground = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vertical_list_item_background);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (sSelectedItems.get(getAdapterPosition(), false)) {
                sSelectedItems.delete(getAdapterPosition());
                mBackground.setSelected(false);
                mLabel.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, android.R.color.black));
            } else {    

                mLabel.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAccent));
                sSelectedItems.put(getAdapterPosition(), true);
                mBackground.setSelected(true);
            }
            sClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    void setOnItemClickListener(UpdateDataClickListener clickListener) {
        sClickListener = clickListener;
    }

    UpdateDataAdapter(ArrayList<UpdateData> myDataset, Context context, int modo) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        mContext = context;
        sSelectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
     }

    @Override
    public UpdateDataAdapter.DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                                 int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.vertical_list_item, parent, false);

        UpdateDataAdapter.DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new UpdateDataAdapter.DataObjectHolder(view);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UpdateDataAdapter.DataObjectHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mLabel.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmTitle());
        if (sSelectedItems.get(position)) {
            holder.mLabel.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAccent));
        } else {
            holder.mLabel.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, android.R.color.black));
        }
        holder.mDateTime.setText(mDataset.get(position).getmSubTitle());
        holder.mBackground.setSelected(sSelectedItems.get(position, false));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public void selected(int position) {

    }

    public void changeMode(int modo) {

    }

    interface UpdateDataClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

}
```

You can set color in selector_row.
[Examples](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/highlight-selected-item-recycler-view/)

Answer (score 0):

You can have an additional `ImageView` in your `RelativeLayou`t and set its color to semi-transparent, e.g.

```
<ImageView
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent"
    android:background="#7000"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

The view has to be non-visible in the beginning.

In your code, set it visible when you need to darken the layout and to `gone` when you need to revert to normal.

Comment: Sorry late reply but how do I add a ImageView into a RecyclerView